# Can I interchange two Xbox 360 hard drives?

Tags: xbox-360

I have two Xbox 360 early gen 60gb hdd (the hard drive is on top, grey and removable).one Xbox has multiple Xbox live accounts but the other Xbox is brand new. The brand new one is physically in better shape but doesn't have Xbox live. The other one is all beat up but has multiple Xbox live accounts. Now the question is, can I take the hard drive from Xbox 1 and put it on Xbox 2 and take HDD from Xbox 2 and put in Xbox 1?

Thank you
J

Answer (score 2):

Yes, my friend has around 10 xbox 360 hard drives and constantly interchanges them with different consoles and he even brings one with him if he is visiting